# Can I pipe multiple ffmpeg outputs to different pipes?

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, mpeg-dash

I have an AWS workflow that streams an audio or video file from S3 to ffmpeg inside a lambda. Which then streams the encoded output back to S3. I want to extend that flow to generate DASH content. On my local device, I can generate the MPD file and the encoded AV files. And there's the problem. Encoding to dash generates at least two files, even with the -single_file flag.

Can I limit the dash export to just the video or MPD file? Or can I somehow pipe the multiple outputs separately through some flag magic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with exporting the video files and MPD file? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Currently, the system works without having to save files directly to the small harddrive space attached to AWS lambdas. Streaming the input file from S3 and the encoded file back to S3 in one pass without touching the space in between. That way it can process files much larger than the 512 MB lambas get. I'm trying to replicate that behavior for dash files.

Answer (score 1):

After rubberducking  here, I found a fatal flaw preventing me from creating a direct upgrade using only lambda services, requiring me to move to ECS containers. Now in that environment, I have access to "infinite" CPU time and harddrive space. So I don't need to stream results to and fro. This doesn't answer my question, but it solves the problem that made me ask it.

As for an actual answer, I don't believe it is possible to tell the dash encoder to pipe specific files. Piping the ffmpeg output is just the MPD file itself which wasn't helpful for my needs. Since I'm using node and fluent-ffmpeg, I could use the progress event to rig up my own external streams to pipe the encoded files on the harddrive to the destination plus a little cleanup magic since mp4 wants to write a header file at the end. But that's lot of manhour work writing a glass cannon compared to the $0.02/hr running an ECS container with a 64gb harddrive.